# Python saving customer minimum order date value per customer from multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have df :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"customer": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "order_date": ["12-12-2022", "12-12-2020", "12-12-2019", "12-12-2018", "12-12-2022", "12-12-2022", "12-12-2015", "12-12-2019", "12-12-2017"]})
```

from which I need the 1st order date (min value) per customer, saved as a new df.
i.e.

```
   customer   1st_order_date
0  foo  12-12-2018
1  bar  12-12-2015
```

how to do it in python?

Comment: Have your tried any pandas grouping operation?

Comment: beginner here, not sure where to start from :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group records by `customer` and aggregate a minimal `order_date` for each group:

```
In [71]: df.groupby('customer')['order_date'].agg('min').to_frame(name='1st_order_date').reset_index()
Out[71]: 
  customer 1st_order_date
0      bar     12-12-2015
1      foo     12-12-2018
```

Comment: this resolved my issue - had to drop NaN values 1st, as unexpectedly there were some NaN values in 'customer'... Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: @Beginnerinthehouse, you're welcome, and happy learning.